# Connect ethernet cable on two router ports can cause loop?

Tags: router, ethernet

If someone connect an ethernet cable from one port of a router to another of its ports, will it cause a loop?

Will internet become unusable?

If yes, then why?

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: It will cause your router to explode and result in a time causality loop. **Do not do this!** Thanks…

Comment: @Giacomo1968 so funny...
Trying this can create data corruption or some unhandled error on my pc?

Comment: You will just create a networking loop that degrades performance until the loop is broken. No data would be corrupted, but networking services might slow down to a crawl rendering networking functions useless.

Comment: @jsotola is this a school answer?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I see, its similar to a fork bomb, but at networking level

Comment: @just_a_developer questions that ask for help with school assignments must contain an attempt at a solution ... also a description of where the student is stuck

Comment: @jsotola I see. Not a school question.
It was a misunderstanding. I thought you were making fun haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, maybe, depends on whether the router ports are switched/bridged (like how almost every *home* router has all of the 'LAN' ports going to an integrated switch) or whether they're truly independent (i.e. the router sees them as separate IP interfaces).

Connecting two Ethernet switch (**bridged**) ports together *will* create a loop, causing trouble both for unicast packets (because the switch will end up learning MAC addresses on the looped ports instead of the correct originating ports) and especially for broadcast packets (which will cycle forever because Ethernet frames do not have a 'hop count' or 'TTL' field so they will be forwarded infinitely). For example:

0. Ports A and B are connected to each other.
1. **One** broadcast packet enters the switch via port X.
2. Copies of the packet leave via all ports, including one via port A and another via port B.
3. Those **two** copies then re-enter via port B and port A respectively.
4. Copies of those *two* packets leave via all ports, including two via port A and two via port B.
5. Those **four** copies then re-enter via port B and port A.
6. Repeat until meltdown.

(And on top of that – let's say if the switch has QoS set up to reserve some bandwidth such that the packet duplication cannot consume all bandwidth – the re-entry in step 3 will cause the switch to incorrectly re-learn the sender's MAC address as being behind port A or B, overwriting 'port X' that was learned in step 1.)

Often switches have protocols to detect the loop preemptively and to automatically disable the ports (either the standard [RSTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol) and/or a simpler proprietary loop-detection protocol), but just as often they don't. In particular, most home routers don't support STP or anything similar. (Though, surprisingly, my home LTE modem seems to speak classic STP.)

On the other hand, if you connect two **routed** ports (router interfaces) together, a loop could still occur but that's less of a problem, partly because a router won't forward broadcasts at all, partly because IP routing is not self-learning in the same way Ethernet switching is (dynamic routing protocols do exist but they're generally loop-free; you have to manually define routes to create a loop), and partly because IP packets have a 'TTL' field which will *eventually* decrement to zero and the packet will be discarded quickly.

Comment: Awesome answer. My questions now are:
1) Can I try this at home? I'm scared about creating data corruption or some unhandled error.
2) How do you write your answers so well?

Comment: Well, to a switch there isn't any difference from normal operation – whether it's handling the infinitely looped packets at full 1 Gbps or whether it's handling a regular file transfer at full 1 Gbps, either way it's doing exactly the same thing that it was built to do – transferring the packets it can and dropping the rest. (Assuming it has sufficient cooling.) Usually the flood of packets goes away as soon as the loop is broken.

Comment: Though all those packets will end up being copied to other ports too – e.g. you asked about a router originally, so if the ports in question belong to a switch that's built-in to a home router, then one copy of everything will go to the router's CPU, possibly overwhelming the OS (and likewise a copy of each packet to your PC, to your Xbox, to your wi-fi connected dryer, etc.) so in the worst case you might need to reboot some device, but generally that should be harmless.

Comment: Generally, if you want to try it, I suggest watching a Wireshark capture on your PC to see what it's receiving live through the network.